# Mixing Sound in Java?

Tags: java, audio, clip

How do I play the same sound more than once at any given time with numerous other sounds going on at the same moment? Right now I've got a "Clip" playing but it won't overlap with itself. ( I hear one bullet fire, the sound finishes then it plays again ). I'm writing  a game with a fast bullet firing system but i can't get the sound to work nicely. It just doesn't sound "right" to hear only one bullet shot every half second when you spawn 20+ on the screen each second.

Any help? Pointers? :D

Answer (score 1):

This seems to answer your question:

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9781598634761/ch09lev1sec3

Quote:

"In other words, a single Clip object cannot mix with itself, only with other sounds. This process works quite well if you use short sound effects, but can sound odd if your sound clips are one second or more in length. [...] If you want to repeatedly mix a single clip, there are two significant options (and one other unlikely option):
1)  Load the sound file into multiple Clip objects (such as an array), and then play each one in order. Whenever you need to play this specific sound, just iterate through the array and locate a clip that has finished playing, and then start playing it again."

So in principle Java does do mixing, just not inside a single clip.

Answer (score 1):

Playing 20 bullit clips at once might be a little cpu intensive. It might be fine. I made a windchime once that played 7 chimes, overlapping (each was about 3 or 4 seconds long), and got away with setting it to play about 100 chimes per 5 second block. But the program wasn't doing anything else.

With Clips, to do this you would need to make multiple copies, and all that audio data would be sitting there, taking up RAM. If they are really short, it's not such a sacrifice. But for rapid fire, the solution most games use is to just cut off the sound and restart. You don't have to play the sound through to the end.

```
myClip.stop();
myClip.setFramePosition(0);
myClip.start();
```

with each bullit start. This is what is most often done. It uses a lot less CPU and less RAM than the overlapping Clip solution.

Answer (score 0):

[AudioClip](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/AudioClip.html) might be what you're looking for - I use it in games playing short .wav sound effects, it's not perfect but it works fine most of the time.

Comment: Using applet.AudioClip causes my game to sporadically freeze. Some some reason it interrupts my game timer.